# In chord symbol notation, how far is "7/6" normally taken?

Tags: chord-theory

Wikipedia has an article on the [7/6 chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_six_chord). It only shows chords built on major triads with added major sixth and minor seventh intervals. For example, a C7/6 chord is comprised of C E G A B♭.

How far is this notation taken? Consider these possibilities:

Cm7/6 - C E♭ G A B♭

Cmaj7/6 - C E G A B

Cmmaj7/6 - C E♭ G A B

C+7/6 - C E G♯ A B♭

C+maj7/6 - C E G♯ A B

Cø7/6 - C E♭ G♭ A B♭

These can certainly be parsed without ambiguity, but are they better-written (or written in a more standard fashion) as Cm7(add6), Cmaj7(add6) and so forth?

Comment: Can't say I've ever come across a 7/6 chord written as such. It comes close to what I'd play for a 13th chord, mainly as dominant 13.  7/6 is what Dad paid for his  marriage licence!

Comment: Whenever you see a sixth in a chord, consider if it could be better notated as rooted in the sixth note. All your examples here could be a variant of A C E G B which is a more standard extended chord, a 9th.

Comment: Of course it could still be rooted in the C. Am9/C, for instance.

Comment: @AJFaraday - that then becomes an Am9. If it is indeed a 'C chord' it'll often have root underneath, so will be called Am9/C

Comment: @AJFaraday - funny, that...

Comment: @Tim “some variant of”

Answer (score 1):

In the notation for chords in jazz, if a chord has 2 modifications, isn't it usual to write last the modification that's furthest from the root? If that's the case here, then your C 7 6 is really C 7 13, the 13 (the A) being a substitute for 5 (G). Typically in a chord of the 13th, the 13th would be voiced above the 7th.

Comment: I've just remembered that classical has it the other way round: a triad in 2nd inversion is called a six-four chord, not a four-six chord.

Comment: Any number larger than 7 attached to a chord automatically includes that 7. (Not 'add' numbers).

Comment: I also think X 7 13 is usual.

Comment: @RosieF that a six-four chord is so called is presumably because the 6 is written above the 4, just as the higher pitch in staff notation is above the lower, and we more naturally read from top to bottom than from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

The picture wikipedia shows is actually a root tone with the sixth and the seventh close together. **So it seems not to be meant a C 7 13**.

But I also never ever came across this notation. (In the final chord of a piece we can often hear a root 7 9 13 chord...)

*In music, a seven six chord is a chord containing both factors a sixth and a seventh above the root, making it both an added chord and a seventh chord. However, the term may mean the first inversion of an added ninth chord (E–G–C–D).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ07u.png)
It can be written as 7/6 and 7,6.[2] It can be represented by the integer notation {0, 4, 7, 9, 10}.*

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_six_chord

To answer your question:

> How far is this notation taken? Consider these possibilities:
>
> Cm7/6 - C E♭ G A B♭
>
> Cmaj7/6 - C E G A B
>
> I don't know whether I like to hear this one: Cmmaj7/6 - C E♭ G A B

I'd say eventually your first 2 examples. But I wouldn't like to listen at the others!